# comparar un archivo local con otro en servidor ftp c#

Tags: c#, ftp, rutas, file

tengo que comparar dos archivos, uno en local y otro en servidor ftp. Lo primero es compararlos por el nombre, si los nombres no coinciden tengo que subir el archivo local al servidor. Si los nombres coinciden tengo que compararlos por  fecha de última modificación y por tamaño, en caso de que las dos comparaciones sean iguales no tengo que hacer nada, y si las comparaciones no coinciden tengo que subir el archivo al servidor ftp.

Os dejo el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
public static void FtpUpdateOrNot(string direccionIP, string username, string password)
{
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server
        Uri uri = new Uri(string.Concat("ftp://", direccionIP, "/Configurator.exe"));
        FtpWebRequest ftpWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(@"C:\Projects\BackUp_\Configurator.exe");  

        Console.WriteLine("The name of the files are the same.");
            if(FtpGetFileSize(ftpWebRequest.ToString(),username,password)==FtpGetFileSize(sourceStream.ToString(),username,password))
            {
                if (FtpGetFileTimestamp(ftpWebRequest.ToString(), username, password) == FtpGetFileTimestamp(sourceStream.ToString(), username, password))
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("We don´t need to update");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                  // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream
                byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Projects\BackUp_\Configurator.exe");

                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                requestStream.Close();

                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

                response.Close(); 
             }
        }
        //if the name are not the same
        else
        {
            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream
            byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Projects\BackUp_\Configurator.exe");

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();  
        }
    }

    // Use FTP to get a remote file's size
    static long FtpGetFileSize(string uri, string username, string password)
    {
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;

        // Get network credentials.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

        try
        {
            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                // Return the size.
                return response.ContentLength;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // If the file doesn't exist, return -1
            // Otherwise rethrow the error
            if (ex.Message.Contains("File unavailable")) return -1;
            throw;
        }
    }

    // Use FTP to get a remote file's timestamp
    static DateTime FtpGetFileTimestamp(string uri, string username, string password)
    {
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;

        // Get network credentials
        request.Credentials =
            new NetworkCredential(username, password);

        try
        {
            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                // Return the size.
                return response.LastModified;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // If the file doesn't exist, return Jan 1, 3000
            // Otherwise rethrow the error
            if (ex.Message.Contains("File unavailable"))
                return new DateTime(3000, 1, 1);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta específica o el problema específico que tienes?

Comment: el código no hace lo que quiero, y no encuentro donde puede estar el fallo o los fallos

Comment: Has depurado tu código? Lee [Te he votado negativamente porque no se aprecia ningún esfuerzo en depurar el código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2872/)

Answer (score 1):

Buenas LopezAi,

Tienes un fallo en la siguiente línea, puede que sea por esto que no te funcione bien el código:

```
if (FtpGetFileTimestamp(ftpWebRequest.ToString(), username, password) == FtpGetFileSize(sourceStream.ToString(), username, password))
```

Estas comparando el valor que retorna `FtpGetFileTimestamp` con el valor que retorna `FtpGetFileSize`.

Debería ser así:

```
if (FtpGetFileTimestamp(ftpWebRequest.ToString(), username, password) == FtpGetFileTimestamp(sourceStream.ToString(), username, password))
```

Por otra banda, lo que tu estás buscando es comparar un archivo local con uno en un servidor `FTP`, por lo tanto, no puedes usar los métodos de `FTP` para el archivo local. Deberías usar la librería [`System.IO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io(v=vs.110).aspx) para la información del archivo local, y te debería quedar así:

```
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\Projects\BackUp_\Configurator.exe");
if(FtpGetFileSize(ftpWebRequest.ToString(), username, password) == fi.Lenght)
{
    if (FtpGetFileTimestamp(ftpWebRequest.ToString(), username, password) == fi.LastWriteTime)
```

Comment: Bueno, aunque tienes razón, dudo que con la función `FtpGetFileTimestamp` pueda obtener la fecha del archivo local, a parte de que dudo que ese método funcione tampoco para el archivo remoto. No creo que esta repuesta sea correcta, lo siento.

Comment: @Marc tienes razón, igualmente no es el problema. Estoy revisando la función _FtpGetFileTimestamp_

Comment: @LopezAi He modificado mi respuesta, mirate-lo

Comment: en otra parte del código, tengoalgunas funciones de upload y download entre local y ftp server, y usando StreamReader me ha funcionado sin ningún problema. He probado tu sugerencia y no me ha servido